# Careers CV print view doesn't transform Markdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, markdown, printing

I love the new little printer icons on the Careers 2.0 site, and I had occasion today to point someone to it.

Unfortunately, I discovered that the print view uses the raw Markdown text, without processing the formatting. *Except* that whitespace is being collapsed because it is rendered as HTML text instead. Here is what my personal statement becomes:

> Having grown up with computers (I had "Winchester" drive platters under my bed and dismantled magnetic core memories for the parts), I naturally rolled into web development in the 90's as the internet came to the mainstream. I now can boast nearly 2 decades of experience in this field, having helped build [Zope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zope) and [Plone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plone_%28software%29), using these tools to build large-scale websites such as Boston.com and intranets for multinationals with thousands of employees. In short, I can make your web tech fly.

Where are my paragraphs? Why are the URLs so ugly? This is what it *should* look like:

> Having grown up with computers (I had "Winchester" drive platters under my bed and dismantled magnetic core memories for the parts), I naturally rolled into web development in the 90's as the internet came to the mainstream.
>
> I now can boast nearly 2 decades of experience in this field, having helped build [Zope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zope) and [Plone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plone_%28software%29), using these tools to build large-scale websites such as Boston.com and intranets for multinationals with thousands of employees. In short, I can make your web tech fly.

Now, I can replace the inline URLs (`[Zope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zope)`) with numbered references (`[Zope][1]` plus `[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zope`) instead, but that won't restore the newline in my text. It doesn't look much better, in fact:

> Having grown up with computers (I had "Winchester" drive platters under my bed and dismantled magnetic core memories for the parts), I naturally rolled into web development in the 90's as the internet came to the mainstream. I now can boast nearly 2 decades of experience in this field, having helped build [Zope][1] and [Plone][2], using these tools to build large-scale websites such as Boston.com and intranets for multinationals with thousands of employees. In short, I can make your web tech fly. [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zope [2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plone_%28software%29

Can we either:

1. not use raw Markdown, just render it to HTML, adding in textual links Markdown-style as numbered references below that section, or
2. same as 1., but damn the URLs, let them read blue underlined text on their print-outs, or
3. use raw Markdown, *let us candidates know explicitly, with a preview in our profile editor* that you do this, and preserve newlines please. That way we can edit for readability both rendered and for printing.

Comment: This also affects lists, which get collapsed into a single paragraph.

Comment: Agreed, the print view needs to be fixed. Thanks for pointing this out! I'll discuss this with @WillCole and check which option will be best.

Comment: In the meantime, note that the PDF export has much better formatting. So, as a workaround, you can export to PDF and print from there.

Comment: @Max: Yup, but without attachments in Careers 2.0 messages, it's easier to point out to interested parties that there is a print option on my profile. As a work-around I shared a link to a PDF copy I generated and put on my server instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's a very good point. Would it help if there was also a PDF option on the public profile?

Comment: @Max: Yes, that would help tremendously. Not every company is fully Web 2.0 enabled and people still ask for a PDF CV from time to time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The print view now correctly renders markdown. Enjoy your neat-looking profile! :-)

Comment: Fantastic! Now I can happily point out the printer icon to prospective contacts. :-) (You may want to edit the Q to replace the `status-planned` tag).

Comment: Done. Status-completed. Thanks! :)